# How to Enable/Disable vibrate for calls and notifications in Android Lollipop?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-audiomanager, android-vibration, android-5.1.1-lollipop

This is not working for Lollipop.

To Enable vibration:

```
audio.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER,
            AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_ON);
audio.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_NOTIFICATION,
            AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_ON);
```

To Disable vibration:

```
audio.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER,
            AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF);
audio.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_NOTIFICATION,
            AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF);
```

This will work fantastically in Kitkat.

Comment: Documentation suggest to use getRingerMode(), but I don't know how to do that in practice:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#VIBRATE_SETTING_ON

Comment: This constant was deprecated in **API level 16.**
But still works fine in _Kitkat._
I want to implement this in _Lollipop._

Answer (score 0):

You can control the vibration on Lollipop with this code:

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), "vibrate_when_ringing", vibrate?1:0);
```

Also you need to add this permission to your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

Please note however, that the above code won't allow you to change the vibration while the phone rings. I guess the phone app reads this setting before the ringing starts, and uses it until the ringing stops.